# What is the difference between the pronunciation of "a" and "e" in a closed syllable?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

What is the difference between the pronunciation of "a" and "e" in a closed syllable? For instance, between the words *than* and *then*? I was told the first should be pronounced with [æ], and the second with [e].

I was studying English from the age of 7, initially before school, then in school, and then in a university. And I still do not know the difference between the two. I have asked several teachers about it, but nobody could answer me. Some of them tried to reproduce the difference by pronouncing the "a" with a widely open mouth and showing the difference with mimics and effort on the face, but the sounds they produced were exactly the same for me. Honestly I think they did not know the difference themselves.

In the university we had some lectures in English by foreigners (I do not know whether English was their native tongue though), and still I did not hear the difference, but the foreigners often could not understand me.

Please tell me the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, in Russian, you already have experience making the sound of English ă (“short a”, IPA /æ/). If you take notice of it, you might be able to learn to hear ă as a distinct vowel. Once you can hear it, you will probably be able to produce this vowel yourself in English, in which the vowel appears in places where it does not occur in Russian.

In Russian, the vowel represented by я and a can have a very different sound in different words, but is heard as “the same” vowel. In English, you must hear these different sounds as different vowels.

The words below illustrate the differences. Pay attention to the *sound of the vowel,* not the palatalization of the preceding consonant.

> я грязный пьяница     Russian я = English ä (IPA /a/), close to f**a**ther, b**a**r, c**a**r
>
> мясо мячик                  Russian я = English ă (IPA /æ/), as in th**a**n, c**a**t, tr**a**p
>
> мастер мать                Russian a = English ä (IPA /a/), close to f**a**ther, b**a**r, c**a**r
>
> это здесь                    Russian э,е = English ĕ (IPA /ɛ/), as in th**e**n, m**e**t, t**e**ll

[The vowel chart on this page](http://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm) shows how the different vowel sounds differ from each other, and includes audio for each vowel sound. Note that Russian *я* and *а* do not correspond in any simple way to any English vowel or even to any IPA vowel. Russian vowels have very different sounds in different contexts, English vowels vary much less in different contexts, and IPA sounds are defined to not vary at all.

[This sentence spoken by the Google Lady](https://translate.google.com/#en/la/After%20lab%2C%20my%20father%20drove%20a%20car%20to%20a%20bar%20and%20fell%20into%20a%20trap.) might help.

Comment: In мастер and мать there is clear а.

Comment: @Anixx Excellent! That's how it sounded when my friend pronounced these. Can you hear the difference from мясо and мячик?

Comment: from what? мясо and мячик use ['а] мать uses [a].

Comment: @Anixx [The Google Lady](https://translate.google.com/#ru/la/мясо%20мячик%0A%0Aмастер%20мать) definitely says /æ/ in мясо and мячик, and /a/ in /мать/. (Her vowel in мастер sounds to me like English "oi".)

Comment: @Anixx Remember, the way to succeed is not to categorize the vowels in the familiar Russian way, but to learn to hear the sounds as different vowels, in the English way.

Comment: Comments for this conversation have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19801/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-kovitz-what-is-the-difference-between-the-pronouncia); please continue the discussion there.

Answer (score 1):

In the weak form "than" and "then" have the same pronunciation with "weak e" (indefinite vowel). Only when stressed "than" is pronounced as æ.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/than

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/then_1

Comment: I suppose it is in American English only?

Comment: As you can see OALD gives the BrE and AmE pronunciation and they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to produce the sounds in your throat/mouth, try this:

For "than" -- lower your jaw, opening your mouth much wider than you'd normally do; exaggeratedly wide, and produce the sound in the back of your throat.

The "then" -- jut your jaw forward, exaggeratedly, and make a breathy sound like zombie. ehhhh...

Then, try to un-exaggerate these facial positions gradually, listening to how the vowel changes as you reposition your jaw bit by bit. See if you can produce two distinct sounds without having to exaggerate the jaw position.

P.S. In rapid speech, the difference between the two sounds can be almost lost.

Comment: "lower your jaw, opening your mouth much wider than you'd normally do; exaggeratedly wide, and produce the sound in the back of your throat." - I can produce nearly any vowel with widely opened mouth, they just would be somewhat distorted (but if I try to produce /e/ wil an open mouth it will be just like normal /e/, without distortions). Should I try to produce /e/ with an open mouth or /a/ or /o/ or /i/?

Comment: "jut your jaw forward, exaggeratedly, and make a breathy sound like zombie. ehhhh..." - what sound the zombies do? If I extend the jaw, I still get clear /e/. In fact whether my mouth is opened or the jaw is put forwars does not affect the /e/ sound at all.

Comment: Look I actually can distinguish two variants of the e vowel (and produce them independently or in the word beginning), the one is that follows soft consonants in Russian, the other that follows hard consonants. I do not know whether they correspond to the English wowels, but I can produce them totally independently of whether my mouth is opened widely and where is my jaw. But I cannot produce the "soft" vowel after a hard consonant and a "hard" vowel after a soft consonant. In "then" and "than" the consonant "th" seems to be hard in both cases, so I can produce only one variant in both cases.

Comment: It is very difficult to say the -e- in "then" with the jaw dropped far down and retracted. Conversely, it is very difficult to say the -a- in "than" with the mouth almost closed with the jaw jutting forward.  Can you distinguish between "man" and "men"?

Comment: The -a- [æ] vowel is not a variant of the -e- vowel. -a- [æ] is a "back vowel" -e- is a mid-to-front vowel.

Comment: you say they differ only by whether the mouth is widely opened, so I thought it is a variant of /e/. But if it is not, what vowel I shell try to produce with my vocal cords, /a/? My vocal cords can produce only five variants: a, e, o, i, u and other vowel distinctions are due to the tongue and lips rather than the cords, so any vowel is a variant of the five. If a as in than does not fall ito the five cells, then please tell me what sound should produce the vocal cords first of all.

Comment: I didn't say that they differed only by whether the mouth was widely opened; I also mentioned the forward-jutting vs. a retracted jaw.  Can you sat "hat"? Can you say "hen"? Those two words have different vowels.  [æ] is deep, far back in the throat, with the throat muscles tensed, not relaxed.

Comment: "I also mentioned the forward-jutting vs. a retracted jaw." - I produce totally the same vowels independently of the position of the jaw. The position of jaw just does not affect anything in my speech. "Can you say "hat"? Can you say "hen"?" - Currently I would pronounce them with the same vowels. I want to know, what should be the difference.

Comment: @Anixx A bunch of things. 1) Let's get our notation straight: symbols in slashes /a/ are [*phonemes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme), meaningful sounds, sounds-as-heard; symbols in square brackets [a] are *phones*, physical sounds, sounds-as-pronounced; and symbols in angle brackets <a> are letters, spelling symbols. 2) /a/ is not an English phoneme, the letter <a> may in different contexts represent the phonemes /æ/ (<fat>) or /ɑː/ (<father>) or /eɪ/ (<fate>). The phone [a] is a component of two phonemic diphthongs, /aʊ/ and /aɪ/ ...

Comment: (<fowl>, <file>)... and in some dialects (mine, for instance) [a] is the phonetic realization of the phoneme /aɪ/ in some contexts. 3) In English, any of these phonemes /æ/, /ɑː/, /eɪ/, /aʊ/, /aɪ/ may follow **any** phonemic consonant and neither the pronunciation of the vowel nor the pronunciation of the consonant is significantly changed. 4) I mis-stated the facts about English palatalization above; all consonant phonemes except /tʃ/, /dʒ/, /θ/, /ð/, /ʃ/, /ʒ/, /r/, /j/ and /w/ may be palatalized BUT this only occurs before the vowel /uː/.

Comment: 6) Unlike Russian, where there are only a few (five or six) vowel phonemes each with many [*allophones*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophone)—markedly different pronunciations in different contexts—English has many (about 20 - it varies somewhat from dialect to dialect) vowel phonemes which vary only a little in different contexts (they are primarily affected by following /r/ or /l/). Consequently, English and Russian speakers hear very differently - we are 'trained' from earliest childhood to hear only **phonemic** differences, not **phonetic** ones.

Comment: @Anixx You do not hear a difference, which is not the same thing as there being no difference. **I** hear a difference. (But *then/than* is a bad example, because in actual speech *than* is never pronounced with a 'full' vowel, as it is in the Google US version: it is always unstressed and pronounced with a 'reduced' vowel, and reduced vowels are very short and very similar to each other.)

Comment: @StoneyB the Google-US versions of than and then sound the same even in full variant, as [e]. The Google-British sounds different, as [a] and [e] respectively. Do you hear at least the difference between Google-US and Google-GB versions of "than"?

Comment: @Anixx The US and Br pronunciations are at opposite ends of the /æ/ spectrum, the US closer to /ɛ/ and the Br closer to /a/. But neither would be mistaken by a native speaker for /ɛ/ or /a/ (and neither has palatalization of the /k/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19781/discussion-between-stoneyb-and-anixx).

Comment: This conversation got a little too lengthy and has therefore been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19786/discussion-on-answer-by-tromano-what-is-the-difference-between-the-pronounciatio).

Comment: I don't know if it's just my pronunciation, but *then* is almost entirely produced my my mouth and throat, while *than* has a nasal aspect to it.  If I plug my nose, *then* is barely altered, but *than* sounds completely different.